# Settings.json to Heroku config

Tags: json, meteor, heroku, settings, heroku-cli

I'm deploying a Meteor/Node app to Heroku.  I have the following lines (for OKGrow analytics) in my settings.json.

```
{
  "public": {
    "analyticsSettings": {
      "Google Analytics": {
        "trackingId": "12345"
      },
      "Segment.io": {
        "apiKey": "abcdef"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, company policy does not allow me to check settings.json into source control.  Is there a way to use Heroku config variables to accomplish this?  Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku [recommends configuring your application via environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

> A better solution is to use environment variables, and keep the keys out of the code. On a traditional host or working locally you can set environment vars in your `bashrc` file. On Heroku, you use config vars.

Fortunately, Meteor [will load settings from the `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings):

> When running your server directly (e.g. from a bundle), you instead specify settings by putting the JSON directly into the `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable. If the settings object contains a key named `public`, then `Meteor.settings.public` will be available on the client as well as the server. All other properties of `Meteor.settings` are only defined on the server. You can rely on `Meteor.settings` and `Meteor.settings.public` being defined objects (not undefined) on both client and server even if there are no settings specified. Changes to `Meteor.settings.public` at runtime will be picked up by new client connections.

So, simply set your app's `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable, e.g. via

```
heroku config:set METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"
```

on your development machine, or by using Heroku's web interface.